# How to create a behavior and send an auto-generated mail after clicking on “Create User” button in Alfresco New User page?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have tried creating a behavior which will ultimately send an auto-generated mail after clicking on Create User button in Alfresco New User page.
Can someone guide how to proceed with this? Earlier I had created a rule which was being invoked whenever I was sending a new user. This rule was managing to send an auto generated mail with the new user name and password.

Though this was almost working, it was a temporary solution as per the users. So now I have to create behavior for auto generating a mail.
Please guide me in this..

```
package com.autoMailgenerate;

import org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException;
import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.Behaviour;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.PolicyComponent;
import org.alfresco.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ChildAssociationRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CreateUserHandler {
     private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreateUserHandler.class);

        private PolicyComponent eventManager;
        private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
            this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
        }

        public void setPolicyComponent(PolicyComponent policyComponent) {
            this.eventManager = policyComponent;
        }

        public void registerEventHandlers() {
            eventManager.bindClassBehaviour(
                    NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.QNAME,
                    ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT,
                    new JavaBehaviour(this, "onaddUser",
                            Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT));


        }


        public void onaddUser(ChildAssociationRef parentChildAssocRef) {
            NodeRef parentFolderRef = parentChildAssocRef.getParentRef();
            NodeRef newuserRef = parentChildAssocRef.getChildRef();

            // Check if node exists, might be moved, or created and deleted in same transaction.
           /* if (newuserRef == null || !serviceRegistry.getNodeService().exists(newuserRef)) {
                // Does not exist, nothing to do
                logger.warn("onaddUser: A new user was added but removed in same transaction");
                return;
            } else {
                logger.info("onaddUser: A new user with ref ({}) was just created in folder ({})",
                        newuserRef, parentFolderRef);
            }*/
            try {
                if (!parentFolderRef.equals("/Repository/User Homes")) {
                    throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("onaddUser: A new user was added but removed in same transaction");
                }
            } finally {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.debug("onaddUser: A new user with ref ({}) was just created in folder ({})",
                            newuserRef, parentFolderRef);
                System.out.println("Creation of user"+newuserRef);
            }

        }


}
```

Created a bean too...

```
   <bean id="com.autoMailgenerate.createUserHandler"
            class="com.autoMailgenerate.CreateUserHandler" init-method="registerEventHandlers">
            <property name="policyComponent">
                <ref bean="policyComponent" />
            </property>
            <property name="serviceRegistry">
                <ref bean="ServiceRegistry" />
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your exact problem is?

Comment: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/176252-how-to-send-mail-with-template-from-java

Comment: @Lista I have to create a behavior which gets invoked as soon as I click on create user button.. and sends a corresponding mail to the new user with their username and password...

Comment: @Imagine not able to understand how to proceed